# Convert a list of values to use as a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to convert a list of values to be used to find a particular key value in a Dictionary.

I am not able to figure out a pythonic way to do it.

Tried converting the list to string and pass as a key to the dictionary, but it is now working as the list contains integer values also.

```
l = ['tsGroups', 0, 'testCases', 0, 'parameters', 'GnbControlAddr', 'ip']

d={
"tsGroups": [{"tsId": 19,
"testCases": [{"name": "abcd",
               "type": "xyz",
               "parameters": {"GnbControlAddr": 
                             {"ip": "192.1.1.1",
                              "mac": "",
                              "mtu": 1500,
                              "phy": "eth2",
                              }
                              }
             }]
             }]
  }

print(d["tsGroups"][0]["testCases"][0]["parameters"]["GnbControlAddr"] 
["ip"])
```

Need to convert input list 'l' to a format to be used as

```
d["tsGroups"][0]["testCases"][0]["parameters"]["GnbControlAddr"]["ip"]
```

Comment: What have you tried till?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [5]: d={ 
   ...: "tsGroups": [{"tsId": 19,"testCases": [{"name": "abcd","type": "xyz", 
   ...:            "parameters": {"GnbControlAddr": { 
   ...:                  "ip": "192.1.1.1", 
   ...:                  "mac": "", 
   ...:                  "mtu": 1500, 
   ...:                  "phy": "eth2", 
   ...: } 
   ...:     }}]}]}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [6]: L = ['tsGroups', 0, 'testCases', 0, 'parameters', 'GnbControlAddr', 'ip']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [7]: functools.reduce?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Docstring:
reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value

Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).  If initial is present, it is placed before the items
of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
sequence is empty.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method

In [8]: t = d                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [9]: for e in L: t = t[e]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [10]: t                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[10]: '192.1.1.1'
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Forgot to update the post. after finding the particular IP need to update it with a different value 'x' in the same json.
x = '10.10.10.10'
So the new JSON should be:

`j={
"tsGroups": [
      {
         "tsId": 19,
         "testCases": [
            {
               "name": "",
               "type": "",
               "parameters": {
                  "GnbControlAddr": {

                     "ip": "10.10.10.10",
                     "mac": "",
                     "mtu": 1500,
                     "phy": "eth2",
}
    }}]}]}`

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak to how pythonic this is, but looping through the list and updating a reference to a new data structure appears to work:

```
current = d
for key in l:
    current = current[key]
print current
```

Comment: What does this add to the previous answer?

Comment: Nothing. Previous answer was probably posted as I was creating this one.